# Delay in message broadcasting and consumption via IBM MQ and codebase is of java

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Problem-

1. I save a particular data in a database on one JVM.
2. An event ( MQ )is published by this JVM which needs to be consumed by 28 JVMs.
3. The message consumption should ideally happen in at max 2 mins.
4. We are seeing that the messages are not consumed and there is a delay in message consumption. We have also seen cases where message consumption happens after 1 day.

How can we avoid this delay in MQ message broadcasting or consumption and also how to resolve this issue through java code?

Comment: You need to look at *where* the delay is. The question as made is far too vague for anyone to give you any meaningful help. Given that they delay you're seeing can be up to a day, it seems unlikely the issue is with IBM MQ. I suggest you instrument both the publishing and consuming applications to ensure you know the exact time messages are published and consumed, then work back from there. MQ's activity trace feature might also help here.

Comment: If it takes a day for your applications to get those messages, my best guess is your applications have a dead-lock or starvation issue ? Any chance to run a simple MQ consumer example on your 28 JVM's instead of or in addition to the current applications ? If you setup that test you might get a feel for your expected consumption time.

Comment: @TimMcCormick Thanks Tim. Actually I have both the publishing and consuming logs set in my code but since MQ is handled by a different team they are saying they don't see issues at MQ level and no message pile up. But as you said I will look more into MQ's activity trace.

Comment: @AxelPodehl Thanks Axel. This is a good information for me to check. I will also check on dead-lock or starvation. But one doubt does dead lock and starvation cause message delay or does it gets dropped.